# Attempting to Implement Functor on Phantom Type

Tags: haskell

Given the following algebraic data type:

`data Foo = Bar Int | Baz Bool deriving Show`

I tried to implement a Functor instance.

```
instance Functor Foo where
    fmap f (Bar x) = Bar (f x)
    fmap f (Baz x) = Baz (f x)
```

But I got this compile-time error:

```
ghci> :l explore/FunctorExplore.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( explore/FunctorExplore.hs, interpreted )

explore/FunctorExplore.hs:3:18:
    The first argument of ‘Functor’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
      but ‘Foo’ has kind ‘*’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Functor Foo’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

So, then I added an `a` in order to attempt to satisfy the compiler:

`data Foo a = Bar Int | Baz Bool deriving Show`

But then I got two errors that, as I understand, basically mean that an `(a -> b)` function can't be applied to an `Int` or `Bool`. `a` is a generic type, whereas the other two are specific.

```
ghci> :l explore/FunctorExplore.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( explore/FunctorExplore.hs, interpreted )

explore/FunctorExplore.hs:4:31:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for fmap :: (a -> b) -> Foo a -> Foo b
          at explore/FunctorExplore.hs:4:9
    Relevant bindings include
      f :: a -> b (bound at explore/FunctorExplore.hs:4:14)
      fmap :: (a -> b) -> Foo a -> Foo b
        (bound at explore/FunctorExplore.hs:4:9)
    In the first argument of ‘Bar’, namely ‘(f x)’
    In the expression: Bar (f x)

explore/FunctorExplore.hs:4:33:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for fmap :: (a -> b) -> Foo a -> Foo b
          at explore/FunctorExplore.hs:4:9
    Relevant bindings include
      f :: a -> b (bound at explore/FunctorExplore.hs:4:14)
      fmap :: (a -> b) -> Foo a -> Foo b
        (bound at explore/FunctorExplore.hs:4:9)
    In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘x’
    In the first argument of ‘Bar’, namely ‘(f x)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

In this situation, it appears to me that a Functor can't be created. Is there more to my question, i.e. what am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

A crucial skill in functional programming is grasping, in a given situation, the right way to do nothing. Classic errors arise, e.g., from giving `[]` meaning "no solutions" as the base case of a recursive search, when `[[]]` meaning "one trivial solution" is needed. Thus also `Functor` instances for phantom types, i.e. constant functors, are useful as the apparently trivial base case of a larger pattern.

I can present the general toolkit for building container-like structures as follows:

```
newtype K a x = K a deriving Functor             -- K for konstant
{- fmap _ (K a) = K a -}

newtype I x = I x deriving Functor               -- I for identity
{- fmap k (I x) = I (k x) -}

newtype P f g x = P (f x, g x) deriving Functor  -- P for product
{- will give (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (P f g), such that
   fmap k (P (fx, gx)) = P (fmap k fx, fmap k gx) -}

newtype S f g x = S (Either (f x) (g x))         -- S for sum
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (S f g) where
  fmap k (S (Left  fx))  = S (Left  (fmap k fx))
  fmap k (S (Right gx))  = S (Right (fmap k gx))
```

Now, any recursive data structure can be presented as a top node which acts as a container for substructures.

```
data Data f = Node (f (Data f))
```

For example, if I want to make binary trees with numbers at the leaves, I can
write

```
type Tree = S (K Int) (P I I)
```

to indicate that the node structure for a tree is either a leaf with an `Int` and *no subtrees* or a fork with a pair of subtrees. I need `K` to point out the *absence* of recursive substructures. The type of trees is then `Data Tree`.

The usual recursion scheme for these things is

```
fold :: Functor f => (f t -> t) -> Data f -> t
fold k (Node fd) = k (fmap (fold k) fd)
```

We don't need to do any work to instantiate that for trees, because `Tree` is already a `Functor`, as it was built from functorial components. The trivial `fmap` for `K Int` amounts to saying that the recursion stops when you reach a leaf.

Of course, these "encoded" data types make it harder to see what you're doing when you write ordinary programs by pattern matching. That's where the `PatternSynonyms` extension comes to your rescue. You can say

```
pattern Leaf i    = Node (S (Left (K i)))
pattern Fork l r  = Node (S (Right (P (I l, I r))))
```

to recover the usual interface. I recommend leaving off the outer `Node`, to fit with the way `fold` strips `Node` for you.

```
pattern Leaf i = S (Left (K i))
pattern Fork l r = S (Right (P (I l, I r)))

add :: Data Tree -> Int
add = fold $ \ t -> case t of
  Leaf i   -> i
  Fork x y -> x + y
```

I've barely scratched the surface of the kinds of generic functionality you can roll out to lots of data types whenever you can develop them just for `K`, `I`, `P` and `S`. The `K` cases are always trivial, but they have to be there.

Similar considerations apply to the `Void` data type (in `Data.Void`). Why on earth would we bother to introduce a data type with no elements worth speaking of? To model the impossible cases of a larger scheme.

Comment: Could you write something about how this relates to the question?  I must admit that I am stumped.

Comment: @Tom Ellis, it shows (a) how to implement a functor instance for a phantom type and (b) why one might choose to do so. In particular it was prompted by the OP's comment on Lee's answer, "I'm guessing it satisfies the laws, but is it useful?".

Answer (score 4):

Since `a` is a phantom type, you can't apply `f` at all, but you can do:

```
instance Functor Foo where
    fmap _ (Bar x) = Bar x
    fmap _ (Baz x) = Baz x
```

Comment: I'm guessing it satisfies the laws, but is it useful? (I don't have much hadkell knowledge - so it's a question, not a comment)

Comment: @KevinMeredith, barely. It's possible you might want such a thing as the base case of some sort of recursion. This is pretty much what the `Functor` instances for `Data.Proxy.Proxy` and `Data.Functor.Constant.Constant` look like.

Comment: It can be very useful! It allows you to pass a `Functor`-like thing in where people expect a genuine `Functor`. You can use this to collect their `fmap`'d functions for later, or to sneak values through a computation without the user knowing.